# javascript sort array of objects by existence of a property while keeping old order

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with about 1,500 elements

```
var a = [
    {
        'name': 'jug',
        'price': 0,
    },
    {
        'name': 'watermelon',
        'price': 47,
    },
    {
        'name': 'pizza',
        'price': 0,
    },
    {
        'name': 'handkerchief',
        'price': 52,
    },
    ..........................
]
```

I keep updating the array with prices as i get data.

I need to re-order the elements with with prices and keep the ones that were on top in the same order.

If that is not so clear lets say you had a web page with products in a certain order, and prices are loading for the products in batches.
I want to put the prices on top and keep it in that order so the products don't jump around. however when i get prices i would like to push it to the bottom after the last price on the list.

Comment: How do you define "on top"? "The first X items must not be sorted"? How large is X then? And if that's what you want: slice the array, keep the first part unsorted, sort the latter part, recombine.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service. Also not clear what expected results are

Comment: how many items shold be kept? are old (already shown items) price information in a new batch?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a.sort(function(a,b){ 

  var priceA = a.price? a.price : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  var priceB = b.price? b.price : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  return a.price-b.price;
});
```

This will ensure that if price is not available, they will stay at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to have the indexOfObj, which is the index of the needed object in your array:

```
var updatedElement = a.splice(indexOfObj, 1); // Remove the element with the updated price
a.push(updatedElement); // Add the new element to the end of the 'a' array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm making a few assumptions here because the question is not very clear to be honest. But I believe you want to do something like this:
(assuming `newprices` is a batch of update data)

```
// if product already in list update price, otherwise insert at bottom
var i, index, newprice;
for(i = 0; i<newprices.length; i++) {
    newprice = newprices[i];
    index = a.findIndex(function(p) { return p.name === newprice.name; });
    if(index > -1) { a[index].price = newprice.price; }
    else { a.push[newprice]; }
}
```

Or maybe you want to do something like this:

```
// put items that get updated prices or are new altogether at the end of the list
var i, index, newprice;
for(i = 0; i<newprices.length; i++) {
    newprice = newprices[i];
    index = a.findIndex(function(p) { return p.name === newprice.name; });
    if(index > -1) { a.splice(index, 1); }
    a.push[newprice];
}
```

But yeah it would definitely help if you state more clearly what you're trying to do...